# Joomla 1.5 multiple registration form

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

i am quite new to joomla and need to create three(3) registration forms and also adding privileges based on the form. Can anyone tell me how to go about this? I am using joomla1.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you asking for is very hard -almost impossible- to achieve using Joomla! 1.5.

I would recommend you upgrade to Joomla! 1.7 since it has a built in system for Access Control and creating different users privileges and you can check [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/). It will be a great place to start from!

Comment: Thanks Ahmad i shall take a look at it